# UIImagePickerController' does not contain a definition for 'DismissModalViewControllerAnimated' Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

I am working on a app for iOS that takes a picture and saves it to the camera roll I am getting this error on the DismissModalViewController:

```
   Severity CodeError   CS1061  'UIImagePickerController' does not contain a definition for 'DismissModalViewControllerAnimated' and no extension method 'DismissModalViewControllerAnimated' accepting a first argument of type 'UIImagePickerController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong heres my code for the class:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using AssetsLibrary;


namespace ToolBelt.iOS
{
    partial class Camera : UIViewController
    {
        public Camera (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        UIImagePickerController imagePicker;
        UIImagePickerController picker = new UIImagePickerController();

        public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

            imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
            imagePicker.PrefersStatusBarHidden();

            imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;

            //Add event handlers when user finished Capturing image or Cancel
            imagePicker.FinishedPickingMedia += Handle_FinishedPickingMedia;
            imagePicker.Canceled += Handle_Canceled;

            //present 
            PresentViewController(picker, true, () => { });
        }

        protected void Handle_FinishedPickingMedia(object sender, UIImagePickerMediaPickedEventArgs e)
        {
            // determine what was selected, video or image
            bool isImage = false;
            switch (e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaType].ToString())
            {
                case "public.image":
                    Console.WriteLine("Image selected");
                    isImage = true;
                    break;
                case "public.video":
                    Console.WriteLine("Video selected");
                    break;
            }

            // get common info (shared between images and video)
            NSUrl referenceURL = e.Info[new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceUrl")] as NSUrl;
            if (referenceURL != null)
                Console.WriteLine("Url:" + referenceURL.ToString());

            // if it was an image, get the other image info
            if (isImage)
            {
                // get the original image
                UIImage originalImage = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.OriginalImage] as UIImage;
                if (originalImage != null)
                {
                    // do something with the image
                    Console.WriteLine("got the original image");
                    imageView.Image = originalImage; // display
                }
            }
            else
            { // if it's a video
              // get video url
                NSUrl mediaURL = e.Info[UIImagePickerController.MediaURL] as NSUrl;
                if (mediaURL != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(mediaURL.ToString());
                }
            }
            // dismiss the picker
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
        }

        void Handle_Canceled(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            imagePicker.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Xamarin iOS to make this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `DismissModalViewControllerAnimated`:

```
imagePicker.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

With `DismissModalViewController`:

```
imagePicker.DismissModalViewController (true);
```

The `Animated` boolean parameter handles the animation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `imagePicker.DismissViewController(true, null);` to dismiss the image picker.

The first parameter indicates whether the controller is dismissed animated or not.

Second parameter is a method which will be called when animation completes.

Comment: @SushiHangover: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController.DismissViewController/p/System.Boolean/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAction/

Comment: Ahhh, can you cast is as a `UIViewController` and have that work?,  as `UIImagePickerController` does not have an `NSAction` param

Comment: @SushiHangover: I don't think you have to cast, I'm just calling method from a base class.

Comment: Ah, ok need more coffee, `DismissModalViewController` vs `DismissViewController`, I typed the wrong method name in my first comment to you as my answer used `DismissModalViewController` and that does not have an nsaction param...